# Date picker max date time is not inclusive

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker.

I'm setting the minimum date to the current date and the max date to December of next year.

```
    minDate = new Date();
    minDate.setDate(1);
    maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    maxDate.setMonth(12);
    maxDate.setDate(0);
    maxDate.setHours(23,59,59);
    $('#startDateInput').datepicker({
        format : "MM yyyy",
        viewMode : "months",
        minViewMode : "months",
        startDate : minDate,
        endDate : maxDate
    });
    $('#endDateInput').datepicker({
        format : "MM yyyy",
        viewMode : "months",
        minViewMode : "months",
        startDate : minDate,
        endDate : maxDate
    });
```

I'm reading the startdate and end date from the datepicker as below:

```
    var startDateString = $('#startDateInput').val();
    var startParts = startDateString.split(' ');
    var startEpoch = new Date(parseInt(startParts[1]) , monthsArray.indexOf(startParts[0].toLowerCase()), 01).getTime();
    document.getElementById('startDate').value = startEpoch;
    var endDateString = $('#endDateInput').val();
    var endParts = endDateString.split(' ');
    var endEpoch = new Date(parseInt(endParts[1]) , monthsArray.indexOf(endParts[0].toLowerCase())+1,0,23,59,59).getTime();
```

I store the epochs in the database.  When I retrieve the dates and show it in the edit form, I'm doing this

```
 if ($('#object').val()) {
        var stDate = new Date(Number("${object.startDate}"));
        var enDate = new Date(Number("${object.endDate}"))
        $('#startDateInput') .datepicker('setDate', new Date(stDate));
        $('#endDateInput').datepicker('setDate', new Date(enDate));
    }
```

Let's say I've selected dec 2019 as input today and saved it. Later when I edit the same form, the endDateInput is not filled because the end date is not inclusive, I suspect.